# Como integrar um banco de dados MySQL com uma aplicação em C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Sou iniciante em banco de dados e tenho uma aplicação simples em C# de cadastros e quero utilizar o banco de dados MySQL para armazenar os dados.

Tenho o MySQL Server instalado e geralmente uso o "command-line client" onde já possuo uma tabela de teste criada "account" contendo as colunas: id, user, e password.
db = "teste".

*Já efetuei a atribuição da referência do "connector MySql.Data.MySqlClient" a classe onde vou efetuar as operações com o bando de dados.

Perguntas:

1. Como posso configurar a connection string corretamente?
2. Após a string ter sido configurada e a conexão ter sido estabelecida, como poderei integrar o banco de dados ao projeto final de C# para poder distribui-lo normalmente "executavel" ou até mesmo mover o projeto de localidade sem ter problemas com o endereço do MySQL da maquina desenvolvedora?
3. Seguindo a questão 2, há uma forma de manter o banco dentro do projeto do C#, onde, poderei modifica-lo gradualmente em diferentes localidades sem tiver nenhum problema quanto a mudança de endereço na string?
4. Quanto a modificação e atualização das tabelas em uma futura atualização no projeto criado, como poderei modifica-lo em meu sql server (atualizar o arquivo mantendo a string de conexão)?

Comment: Cara, coloque aqui o que você tentou e o erro que encontrou. Se não tentou, uma simples lida na documentação ou em um exemplo prático que você encontra no primeiro resultado do Google para "mysql c#" responde a maioria das suas perguntas.

Answer (score 2):

## Como posso configurar a connection string corretamente?

[Você pode usar um arquivo `udl` pra isso](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/189680/pt-br). O client do MySQL precisa estar devidamente instalado na sua máquina.

### Após a string ter sido configurada e a conexão ter sido estabelecida, como poderei integrar o banco de dados ao projeto final de C# para poder distribui-lo normalmente "executavel" ou até mesmo mover o projeto de localidade sem ter problemas com o endereço do MySQL da maquina desenvolvedora?

A melhor maneira é gerenciando seu projeto usando pacotes. No caso do C#, [a solução chama-se NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/). [O pacote do MySQL no NuGet é acessível aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).

Sua preocupação será apenas copiar os arquivos para a máquina de destino, sem se preocupar com instalações e coisas do tipo.

### Seguindo a questão 2, há uma forma de manter o banco dentro do projeto do C#, onde, poderei modifica-lo gradualmente em diferentes localidades sem tiver nenhum problema quanto a mudança de endereço na string?

Sim, mas isso fará você abandonar o MySQL e usar um banco de dados cujo formato seja local. Há duas ótimas tecnologias de banco de dados para isso:

- [Microsoft SQL Server LocalDB](http://codigoecafe.com/2013/03/12/localdb-uma-alternativa-simples-e-rapida/);
- [SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite);

### Quanto a modificação e atualização das tabelas em uma futura atualização no projeto criado, como poderei modifica-lo em meu sql server (atualizar o arquivo mantendo a string de conexão)?

Você pode usar um Framework de abstração de dados que faça esse controle incrementalmente, como o [EntityFramework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/).